# Recognition of curved text

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

Let's say I have some generic picture that contains curved text.
Let's also say I have a good detector and I'm able to create bounding polygons correctly, for example using [this](https://github.com/Yuliang-Liu/Curve-Text-Detector).
How can I recognize (read) what's inside the polygons? As far as I know I can't apply something like CRNN since I would need rectangle-like bounding boxes. Any clue will be appreciated.

Additional details that could help:

- The curvature can be assumed constant
- I can't assume the text will be "frontal" (there can be projective distortions)
- I need the process to be near real time (~2 frames per second on GPU)

Comment: Try to transform the bounding polygon to resemble a rectangle -> apply the same transformations to the image?

Comment: it makes sense conceptually, but what could be a way to do that?

Comment: If it was that easy, the linked repo would already do that. I'd probably try to rotate the image so that one edge is straight, then level the opposite end to similar height, then somewhat get rid of the curvature between them.